# How to organize database with Room

Tags: android, android-room

I am creating an app which needs to show events based on date and time. I imagine it something like this:
[image]

For each date, I have time, each of which has something inside. Based on previous project, I started implementation with Room. However I got stuck on my first query with the error that my primary key is not unique. Which makes sense, since am I using @Insert which will add new row with the same ID (the date). How should I organize the DB, so I can have something like the above picture?
How can I get the the first row from first table and add underneath?

Or I should use JSON instead, since my DB won't be that big (I can store in JSONs per month).

Comment: If your primary key is not unique, then it is by definition not a primary key.

Comment: The real question is, why do you have a separate date/time table when you could technically solve this problem with an EVENT table and a BIGINT (date).